# Shell script sleep timing is off when run from Automator

Tags: bash, automator

I have a shell script that plays a mantra and three bells for meditation.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

log=~/Dropbox/code/meditation/meditation.log
bell_path=~/Dropbox/code/meditation/meditation_bell/

echo $(date) "Mantra begin." >> $log
afplay ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/Unknown\ Artist/Unknown\ Album/楞嚴咒〔靈巖山寺早課版〕.m4a &&
    echo $(date) "Mantra done." >> $log
afplay ${bell_path}bright_bell.mp3 &&
    echo $(date) "Bright bell done." >> $log
sleep 1800 # 30 minutes
afplay ${bell_path}small_bell.mp3 &&
    echo $(date) "Small bell done." >> $log 
sleep 900 # 15 minutes
afplay ${bell_path}big_bell.mp3 &&
    echo $(date) "Meditation done." >> $log &&
    echo >> $log
```

I use Automator to create an app that runs at a fixed time every morning on the Calendar.app.

[image]

But somehow, the timing of the bells get messed up when run through Automator, as indicated by the log below.

[image]

The mantra lasts about 40 minutes while each bell is less than a minute. Any idea what is happening over here?

---

## Update:

After adding quotes to my code as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

log=~/Dropbox/code/meditation/meditation.log
bell_path=~/Dropbox/code/meditation/meditation_bell/

echo "$(date) Mantra begin." >> $log
afplay ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Music/Unknown\ Artist/Unknown\ Album/楞嚴咒〔靈巖山寺早課版〕.m4a &&
    echo "$(date) Mantra done." >> $log
afplay "${bell_path}bright_bell.mp3" &&
    echo "$(date) Bright bell done." >> $log
sleep 1800 # 30 minutes
afplay "${bell_path}small_bell.mp3" &&
    echo "$(date) Small bell done." >> $log 
sleep 900 # 15 minutes
afplay "${bell_path}big_bell.mp3" &&
    echo "$(date) Meditation done." >> $log &&
    echo >> $log
```

The script ran correctly when run with the 'play' button in Automator.

[image]
[image]
[image]

But failed when the app is executed automatically by Calendar.app

[image]

Comment: Bright bell should sound immediately after the mantra, which is about 40 minutes. Wait 30 minutes. Sound small bell. Wait 15 minutes. Sound big bell. Meditation done.

Comment: The log shows that time interval between the events are very unpredictable. (Only the interval between small bell and big bell [indicated by "Meditation done."] stays at 15 min. )

Comment: You need to start quoting your shell variables, i.e. `afplay "${bell_path}small_bell.mp3" && echo "$(date) Small bell done." >> "$log"`.  As for the approach to what you're doing, I think a better way would be to use `launchd`, which will be able to schedule scripts, etc. to execute at specific times, or time intervals, and do it in an efficient manner, rather than using `sleep`, which is a blocking command.  I'll go through this more later (after work).

Comment: Would `launchd` work even when the user is logged out?